# ansible vs cronjob for background job to label dynamic nodes

Tags: ansible, docker-swarm, cron-task

Need to change the labels of worker nodes with a predefined combination of alphanumeric characters (example: machine01) as and when they join the cluster (again and again if node(s) leave or when new nodes join the cluster). Is it possible to do it using ansible or we need to setup a cronjob. If possible using ansible, I would like to have a hint on how we can run a playbook once and keep it active in background to keep on checking new node labels. Which is more cheap computationally.

Comment: please put more description to your question and what have you tried so far

Comment: Can you provide more information and description about your environment, infrastructure and what you try to achieve how? Currently it is fully unclear and one can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

> *How we can run a playbook once and keep it active (annot.: running) in background to keep on checking new node labels?*

Since Ansible is a push based [Configuration Management](https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/configuration-management) tool, it is not designed and developed for such use case. Ansible will just [connect to](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/connection_details.html)  the remote device via SSH and perform a configuration task.

**Further Documentation**

- [Ansible concepts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/getting_started/basic_concepts.html)
- [Ansible playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html)